# Hide expand / collapse icon for specific row

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to hide the expand icon in the grid when a certain condition is true. For instance, if my table data does not have any values in the underlying array. I know I can disable the icon by setting `p-column => expander` to `false` but then I don't have any icon for all the rows. I need to enable it for a specific row based on current grid data. I don't find any way to retrieve the current row data in a `<p-column>`element.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="testData" [expandableRows]="true">
  <p-column expander="true"></p-column>
  <p-column header="name">
    <template pTemplate let-row="rowData">
      {{row.name}}
    </template>
  </p-column>

  <template let-data pTemplate="rowexpansion">
    {{data.values | json}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let v of data.values">{{v | json}}</li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</p-dataTable>

this.testData = [
      {name: 'a', values: [
        'a', 'b', 'c'
      ]},
      {name: 'b', values: []}, // I don't need an expand icon when there are no values
    ];
```

[image]
Plunker to play with: https://plnkr.co/edit/JMMMMNLekNpNa393hHcz?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
  <p-column>
     <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <a *ngIf="true/false" (click)="YOUR_TABLE_ID.toggleRow(row)">Toggle</a>
     </ng-template>
  </p-column>
```

I had the same problem and figured it out with this template column.

NB this is for Angular 4, just change ng-template to template for ng2.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to show/hide my row expander button/icon depending on some condition of my row. This is how I did it.

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="students" selectionMode="single" [responsive]="true" [lazy]="false" resizableColumns="true" expandableRows="true" [loading]="dataTableDataLoading" class='primeNGDataTable' [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="600px" #dtStudents>
   <p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}">
      <ng-template let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
         <a *ngIf="data.addresses !== null && data.addresses.length > 0" (click)="dtStudents.toggleRow(data)">
            <i *ngIf="!dtStudents.isRowExpanded(data)" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" [style]="{'margin-top':'5px'}"></i>
            <i *ngIf="dtStudents.isRowExpanded(data)" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
         </a>
      </ng-template>
   </p-column>
   <p-column header="ID" field='id' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
   <p-column header="First Name" field='fname' [style]="{'width': '120px'}"></p-column>
    <ng-template let-data pTemplate="rowexpansion">
       <p-dataTable selectionMode="single" [value]="data.addresses" [lazy]="false" [responsive]="true">
          <p-column header="Address Line 1" field='addressLn1' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
          <p-column header="Address Line 2" field='addressLn2' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
          <p-column header="City" field='city' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
          <p-column header="State" field='state' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
          <p-column header="Zip" field='zip' [style]="{'width': '80px'}"></p-column>
       </p-dataTable>
   </ng-template>           
 </p-dataTable>
```